# Recover data from folder that was target of mount

Tags: mount

I had a folder `/acme`, that contained data.  I found out that I was supposed to have already mounted `/dev/centos/lv_acme` to `/acme`.  I did a minimum amount of research on the web, and it appeared that mounting did not erase data.  (Though I now assume I misunderstood what I read.)

I executed the command

```
mount /dev/centos/lv_acme /acme
```

As I'm sure you've figured by now, `/acme` no longer contains my data.  Is there any way of recovering the data that was in `/acme`?

Comment: The question was already answered before it was incorrectly marked as a duplicate.  Amazing how five people can agree on something wrong.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Easy,

```
umount /acme
```

Your original `/acme` directory is simply "hidden" under the mount point.

If nothing prevents you to umount the dir, you can umount it, copy the data elsewhere and remount it.

Comment: I frequently put a file named simply `not-mounted` in a directory that is _supposed_ to be used as a mount point -- if I can see the file, then I know the volume isn't mounted. Unmounting the volume makes the file visible again.

Answer (score 15):

Mounting does not erase data, but it might hide data since the contents of the mountpoint are replaced with the mounted filesystem (which may be empty). Of course, there may be side effects (programs that behave differently depending on how things are mounted), so things can still go horribly wrong when you mismanage your mountpoints.

If you mounted an empty filesystem in the wrong place, simply umounting would do:

```
umount /acme
```

If you want to see what is below a mountpoint without umounting it, you can bind-mount the parent filesystem elsewhere:

```
mkdir /mnt/root
mount --bind / /mnt/root
ls /mnt/root/acme
```

It's more difficult if there are more filesystem layers mounted over one another. Use `lsblk` and `cat /proc/mounts` to figure out the structure. You can bind-mount each layer separately in a temporary directory and check out the contents.

Note those bind-mounts are writable by default so it's possible to change, rename and remove files. For a read-only view, just add `--read-only`.

Answer (score 3):

If you can't unmount the mounted filesystem the original can still be reached by mounting it on a temporary mount point and accessing the files that way.